# Should a question mark follow "I (do) believe"?

Tags: grammaticality, question-mark

Should a question mark be used after

> "I believe"

or

> "I do believe"

My brain hurts from not being 100% correct. My O.C.D won't let it go.

Comment: Weird. Starting with your first example,  are you asking whether you should write "I believe." or "I believe?" The answer depends on the context I suppose, but even taking that into account, "I believe?" is kind of strange. Do you know what you believe or not? You tell me. You might want to set your O.C.D. to work on that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No.  That's because both of those examples are statements, not questions.

Unless there's something about the wider context that makes them question, don't put question marks after them.

Comment: Absolutely. You'd have to say "Do I believe?" For it to need a question mark. Also @Richard Kayser is right, even this question would only be used rhetorically by most people.